# Calculate time difference in PSQL with HH:MM splitted in several columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've a PSQL table like this:

| Order | Start_Hour | Start_Minute | Finish_Hour | Finish_Minute |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 10 | 15 | 12 | 15 |
| 10 | 12 | 15 | 14 | 15 |
| 10 | 16 | 00 | 17 | 00 |

And I need to calculate by a query the total time expressed in hours that I spent to finish the order. In this scenario I expect to have a total of 5 hours:

```
12:15 - 10:15 = 2 hours 
14:15 - 12:15 = 2 hours 
17:00 - 16:00 = 1 hours
```

The query result must be 5.

The idea was concatenate start hour/minute and finish hour/minute, convert them to hour, make the difference, calculating the total.

```
SELECT (Start_Hour & ":" & Start_Minute) as start, (Finish_Hour & ":" & Finish_Minute) as finish

FROM OrderDetails
```

But when I try to convert them to HH:MM using cast or convert but I got errors.

Any advice?
Thank you

Comment: Maybe your data design could be improved as `(order integer, start_time timestamp, finish_time timestamp)`. Then querying would be much easier and cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

This query uses `make_time` as Adrian Klaver suggests.

```sql
select 
  "Order", 
   sum(extract(hour from 
        make_time("Finish_Hour", "Finish_Minute", 0) - 
        make_time("Start_Hour",  "Start_Minute",  0))
      ) as duration
from the_table
group by "Order";
```

However I have remarks about your data design. Hour and minute are not enough for storing time because (apart from missing precision and other reasons) the end time might be over midnight. You have a specific data type for this - `timestamp`. I would suggest something like

```sql
create table the_table 
(
  order_nr integer, 
  start_time timestamp, 
  finish_time timestamp
);
```

Also note that using mixed case names in Postgresql requires double-quoting.

Answer (score 0):

Use [make_time](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html):

```
 select  make_time(12, 15, 0) - make_time(10, 15, 0);
 ?column? 
----------
 02:00:00
```

Where in your case you would substitute in Start_Hour, Start_Minute, Finish_Hour, Finish_Minute.

Comment: Could it be that "Start_Hour" is before midnight  and "Finish_Hour" - after it?